# File get contents and cURL error

Tags: php, curl, httprequest, file-get-contents

I have problems with "file_get_contents" and "cURL". When I make this:

```
$myFile = 'http://example.com/asset_compress/assets/get/bbb.js?file%5B0%5D=myfile.js';
$a=file_get_contents( $myFile );
```

I get this error:

```
Warning (2): file_get_contents
(http://example.com/asset_compress/assets/get/bbb.js?file%5B0%5D=myfile.js)
 [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: 
    HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
   [APP/Controller/MyController.php, line 1373]
```

Then I tried CURL like this:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $myFile);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $this->userAgent);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
$a = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

And I get this error:

```
404 Not Found: The resource requested could not be found on this server!
```

But when I write `http://example.com/asset_compress/assets/get/bbb.js?file%5B0%5D=myfile.js` to my browser's address bar, I get the file perfectly. The headers of the browser is like this:

```
Request URL:http://example.com/asset_compress/assets/get/bbb.js?file%5B0%5D=myfile.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK

Request Headers
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:tr,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:example.com
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.28 Safari/537.31

Query String Parameters
file[0]:myfile.js

Response Headers
Connection:close
Content-Length:15911
Content-Type:application/javascript; charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 29 Mar 2013 20:33:43 GMT
Server:Apache
X-Powered-By:PleskLin
```

I suspected file_get_contents and when I make this, I get output perfectly:

```
$d1 = file_get_contents("http://www.yahoo.com");
print_r($d1);
```

When I try cURL I get 404 error. How can I more diagnose why I get 404, despite that I get 200 from browser request.

Comment: try `url_decode`ing `$myFile`

Comment: Maybe there's a proxy interfering with HTTP requests coming from your webserver.

Comment: `CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER` in `curl_setopt`? set `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` and run by cli: `php script_with_curl.php`.

Comment: @Crisp `$myFile = urldecode('http://example.com/asset_compress/assets/get/bbb.js?file%5B0%5D=myfile.js')` didn't help.

Comment: @mkjasinski I added autorefferer and verbose. But output is same.

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept-Encoding: gzip"));`?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, have you tried ```http://example.com/asset_compress/assets/get/bbb.js?file[0]=myfile.js``` or ```http://example.com/asset_compress/assets/get/bbb.js?file[]=myfile.js``` directly in curl?  I know it's redundant, but it's worth ruling out.

Comment: @methai Hmm how can I call cURL directly?

Comment: @trante from command line (Mac, Linux): `curl -v "http://example.com/asset_compress/assets/get/bbb.js?file\[\]=myfile.js"`

Answer (score 0):

This being hosted on a local computer? Or else where? 
I was having an similar issue that my host determined to be an ISP down the line blocking my requests.

Comment: File is stored in remote webserver.

Comment: Perhaps see if your web host can run a  traceroute on the URL in question directly from the server and see what hop its dying.

Comment: Sorry if I told wrong. Both *MyController.php* and *bbb.js* files are on the same server and same domain.